# Data Not Sending to Sheet as Expected: Issues with Item Details View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on an item details view, where user interactions are meant to display item information for editing when an existing item is clicked, and to create a new item when the "New Item" button is clicked. However, I've encountered a bug in this process:

The item details view only displays the item details after clicking the "Add Item" button first. If I don't do this initially, it simply presents a new item instead every time.

This is my code:

```
struct ItemListView: View {
    @Query private var allItems: [Item]
    @State private var isPresented: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedItem: Item?
    @State private var createItem: Bool = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(allItems) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            createItem = false
                            selectedItem = item
                            isPresented.toggle()
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                createItem = true
                isPresented.toggle()
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Add item")
                }
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.tip.crop.circle")
                    Text("Edit items")
                }
            })
        }.padding()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Items")
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
        /* The item details view only displays the selected item after clicking the "New Item" button has been pressed. 
In other words, the item details are not presented until after clicking the "New Item" button. */
        ItemDetailsView(item:createItem ? Item() : selectedItem!)
    }
    }
}
```

I'm seeking assistance to resolve these issues and ensure that the item details view functions correctly. Any guidance or insights into what might be causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use sheet(item:)

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be simpler

```
struct ItemListView: View {
@Query private var allItems: [Item]
@State private var selectedItem: Item?

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(allItems) { item in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(item.name)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedItem = item
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                selectedItem = Item()
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus")
                    Text("Add item")
                }
            })
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                
            }, label: {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "pencil.tip.crop.circle")
                    Text("Edit items")
                }
            })
        }.padding()
    }
    .navigationTitle("Items")
    .sheet(item: $selectedItem) { item in
        ItemDetailsView(item: item)
    }
  }
}
```